# R$^2$ after adding one variable

Tags: regression, r-squared

An interesting question my friend told me: I have two simple linear regression models with R$^2$ = 0.1

```
Y ~ X1
Y ~ X2
```

If I combine these two models, `Y ~ X1 + X2`, is it possible that R$^2$ > 0.2? If so, can you provide an example?

Comment: Why is that a surprise?

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

This doesn't get your numbers on the nose, but the spirit is the same

```
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
  x2 = c(0, 1, 2, -1, 0, 1),
  y = c(0, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6)
)
```

With model $R^2$ statistics

```
> summary(lm(y ~ x1, data=df))$r.squared
[1] 0.2727273
> summary(lm(y ~ x2, data=df))$r.squared
[1] 0.2066116
> summary(lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=df))$r.squared
[1] 1
```

Comment: This example shows that the R$^2$ for the sum of the Xs can be greater than the sum of the two R$^2$s. As you say you can probably manipulate the data values to make the original two R$^2$s =0.1 and make the R$2$ for the sum greater than 0,2.  But since the sum in your example is (0,1,2,0,1,2) and y=(0,2,4,2,4,0) how can the R$^2$=1? There is not perfect correlation. Is x1+x2 in the code actually the sum or is it the least squares linear combination of x1 and x2 including an intercept?

Comment: `y ~ x1 + x2y` is not a sum but `R` code for: explain y linearly through x1, x2 and an intercept. This is a OLS model with an intercept, even though this intercept happens to be `0`. It's $y\leftarrow 4\times x_1+2\times x_2 + 0 + \epsilon$. with $\epsilon=0$.